# How to use back reference with stringi package?

Tags: r, backreference, stringi

In R I can use `\\1` to reference to a capturing group. However, when using the stringi package, this doesn't work as expected.

```
library(stringi)

fileName <- "hello-you.lst"
(fileName <- stri_replace_first_regex(fileName, "(.*)\\.lst$", "\\1"))

[1] "1"
```

Expected output: `hello-you`.

In [the documentation](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjABahUKEwjGyL7sicTHAhXM2xoKHQFIC-M&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Fstringi%2Fstringi.pdf&ei=WkrcVcazL8y3a4GQrZgO&usg=AFQjCNEddqS0VrhQActoyvP6USGHEZqOiw) I couldn't find anything concerning this problem.

Comment: Change the `\\1` to `$1`, from the doc (`?stri_replace_first_regex`): References are of the form $n, where n is the number of the capture group (their numbering starts from 1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `$1` instead of `\\1` in the replacement string:

```
library(stringi)

fileName <- "hello-you.lst"
fileName <- stri_replace_first_regex(fileName, "(.*)\\.lst$", "$1")

[1] "hello-you"
```

From the [doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/stringi.pdf), `stri_*_regex` uses [ICU's regular expressions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)